# Fourier Transform of the Weierstrass Function

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm looking to compute the Fourier Transform of the Weierstrass Function over the interval $[0,2\pi]$:
$$W(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n \cos(b^n t) $$
where $0<a<1$, $b$ is a positive integer such that and $ab > 1+\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

In computing the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n\cos(b^nt)e^{2\pi i st}dt$$
I've tried writing $\cos(b^nt) = \frac{e^{ib^nt }+e^{-ib^nt}}{2}$. I use geometric series to get rid of the sum, but then I get the integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{2\pi i s t}}{2}e^{ibt} \left(\frac{1}{1/a-e^{ibt}} + \frac{1}{1/a-e^{-ibt}} \right)dt $$
which I don't know how to solve, even when I put it under a common demoninators and right the bracketed expression in terms of $\cos(bt)$.

I've also tried interchanging the sum and the integral. However, I get an unwiedly sum.

Is there a clever way of going about this or am I missing something in one of these methods.

Comment: The sum is from $n=1$ to $\infty$?

Comment: yes, the sum starts at $1$

Comment: and goes to $\infty$?

Comment: yes, i've corrected the error

Comment: If you meant that $b$ is an integer then $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n \cos(b^n t)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic Fourier series, for $b$ not an integer the Fourier coefficients of its restriction to $[0,2\pi]$ are complicated and not of the form you got.

Comment: Yes, assume $b$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

For $b$ an integer $\ne -1,0,1$ and $|a|<1$ then $$W(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n \cos(b^n t)$$ is already a $2\pi$-periodic Fourier series and
$$
c_k=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} W(t)e^{-ikt}dt = 
\begin{cases}\dfrac12 a^{n} & \text{if } |k| = |b|^n\\
\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
$$
W(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{ikt}$$

Comment: I see why you can write $W(t)$ as a exponential Fourier series, but I don't see why the Fourier transform of a Fourier series is zero at non-integral values. I.e., why $\mathcal{F}(W)(s) =0$ for $s\notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you mean with "the Fourier transform" ? For $k$ not an integer then $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} W(t)e^{-ikt}dt$ is non-zero, it is for $|k|$ an integer but not a power of $b$ that it is $0$. And the Fourier transform in the sense of distributions of $W(t)$ (not restricted to $[0,2\pi]$) is $\sum_k c_k \delta(\omega-k)$.

Comment: I meant the integral transformation. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify the sum you get.

Comment: No, it is obvious that it doesn't simplify, why do you care of it ? $$F(W)(k)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} W(t)e^{-ikt}dt=\frac1{2\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n (\frac{e^{2i\pi (b^n-k)}-1}{2i(b^n-k)}+\frac{e^{2i\pi (-b^n-k)}-1}{2i(-b^n-k)})$$   ${}{}{}$

Comment: Looking to establish whether W has a weak derivative.

Comment: For $|ba|>1$ it doesn't because $ik c_k$ is not bounded.

Comment: I don't follow. How does $kc_k$ factor into things? Are you using the derivative formula for the Fourier transform?

Comment: The derivative formula for the **Fourier series coefficients**, which is just an integration by part. If $f,f'$ are $L^1[0,2\pi]$ and $2\pi$ periodic then $c_k(f')  = ik c_k(f)$ and $|c_k(f')|\le \frac1{2\pi}\|f'\|_{L^1[0,2\pi]}$. Here $ib^n c_{b_n}(W) = i b^n a^n$ so $W'$ can't be $L^1$. In fact $c_k(f')  = ik c_k(f)$ is always true when $f$ is a distribution (in which case the Fourier series converge in the sense of distributions).

Comment: If $W$ had a weak derivative, then since has a convergent Fourier series, would this implies that its weak derivative must also have a convergent Fourier series given by the formula?

Comment: Here yes $W'$ is $L^1$ iff $|ab|<1$ so its Fourier series converges uniformly but for other kind of functions no (the case $|ab|=1$ needs a special discussion based on Riemann-Lebesgue lemma). There are some continuous functions whose Fourier series diverges.